# Ssh client through a specific interface

Tags: networking, ssh

How can i force a client connection ssh to communicate through a specific interface ?

I have a server with eth0 and eth1 i.e., and i want to force all ssh clients to pass through eth0. So i could access my server via eth1 faster when there is a lot of ssh clients on my server.

Edit : It's the server who initiates the ssh client connections.

Comment: Your stated reason is probably fallacious. Unless SSH clients are dong file transfers or tunneling, the traffic is extremely sporadic.

Comment: if you are problem is solved then post your answer or accept the one from list given here. if you don't want to debug further it is better to close the question or delete the question as it doesn't solve the purpose of posting question to seek answer and then left it in between

Comment: ooops just noticed i wasted a whole bunch of time trying to answer a 2 year old question - and still got it wrong

Comment: os level solution is to route all ssh traffic, to your eth0 using iptables as Sujal user proposed.

Answer (score 5):

Update OPs edit asks for server side solution - this is client side.
For temporary use you can bind option to SSH from particular IP or ethernet port.
ssh target_IP -b source_IP

For more permanent solution change the routing table.

I cam trying to ssh into 172.x.x.69 from 172.x.x.7 (eth0) which has another Ethernet port 172.x.x.8 (eth1) that happens to be the default gateway.

Fails if i try to ssh directly - because this source IP defaults to x.x.x.8 eth1 and this is not allowed in external firewall rules to .69

```
# ssh 172.29.179.69 -l root
ssh: connect to host 172.x.x.69 port 22: Connection timed out
#
```

Success when I bind SSH to x.x.x.7 IP (eth0) using the -b switch - this IP is allowed to connect to .69 in firewall rules.

```
# ssh 172.x.x.69 -b 172.x.x.7 -l root
Last login: Wed Nov 19 14:27:44 2014 from 172.x.x.7
#
```

At 172.x.x.7 I have two ethernet ports x.7 and x.8

```
# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxxxx
          inet addr:172.x.x.7  Bcast:172.x.x.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: xxx Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27678 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1852058 (1.7 MiB)  TX bytes:684 (684.0 b)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxx
          inet addr:172.x.x.8  Bcast:172.x.x.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: xxx Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:72022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:40788643 (38.8 MiB)  TX bytes:4441314 (4.2 MiB)
```

The reason I need this hack is the routing table default eth1 instead of eth0

```
# route (@172.x.x.7)
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.x.x.0       *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth1
172.x.x.0       *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth2
default         172.x.x.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1 # eth0 OK
#
```

Comment: I see this doesn't answer the question as OP talks about server eth0 which is simply commented earlier "don't give out the secret O&M IP"

My answer solves the problem I had today.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some rules to "iptables" to forward your ssh traffic initiated from box to remote machine.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -p tcp --dport 22 -d [destination ip] -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: wtf, this forwards connections passing through a router from eth1 to eth2. It does nothing for connections to/from the router.

Answer (score -1):

Only tell other users the eth0's ip address.